# Does this joint weak convergence result hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of random variables weakly converging to $X$ ($X_n\Rightarrow X$) as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I am trying to determine the most general conditions on a function $f$ such that we have the joint weak convergence $(X_n, f(X_n))\Rightarrow (X,f(X))$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Using the following:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_n \in A, f(X_n)\in B)=\mathbb{P}(X_n\in A \cap f^{-1}(B)),$$

where $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets, it would appear that we can conclude via the weak convergence of $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$. However, I am not sure how rigorous this argument is, and for which functions $f$ this would hold? I have a feeling the result should hold if $f$ is just measurable. I am not sure how one could prove this, but the idea comes from the fact that the continuous mapping theorem is also valid for measurable functions with a negligible set of discontinuities. Any comments or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What follows after "we can write:" is true for *any* suitable function $f$. You don't need continuity and/or one-to-one for that. With this however I don't mean to say that you are right, but more that I don't understand your argumentation that it works for continuous functions that are one-to-one. I have reason to believe that it works if $f$ is continuous, but on other grounds.

Comment: @drhab, thanks for your input, I will change accordingly. Using the same argument, can we deduce the weak convergence if $f$ is only measurable?

Comment: I have my doubts about that. If I can find an answer then you will get it.

Comment: @drhab ok thanks. My idea was using the mapping theorem for measurable functions (with a finite set of discontinuities) i.e. define $g$ such that $g(X_n)=(X_n, f(X_n))$. Does this seem plausible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be the characteristic function of $(-\infty,0]$.

Let it be that $X_n=\frac1{n}$ a.s. and $X=0$ a.s.

For every continuous and bounded $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have: $$\mathbb Eg(Xn)=g\left(\frac1{n}\right)\to g(0)=\mathbb Eg(X)$$

This means that $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$.

But $f(X_n)=0$ a.s. and $f(X)=1$ a.s. so $f(X_n)$ is *not* converging weakly to $f(X)$.

Then evidently $(X_n,f(X_n))$ is *not* converging weakly to $(X,f(X))$.

---

On the other hand if $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous
and bounded function, then $$h:=g\circ\left(1\times f\right)\circ\delta$$
where $\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto\langle x,x\rangle$
will be continuous and bounded if $f$ is continuous.

If $X_{n}$ converges weakly to $X$ - we find: $$\mathbb{E}g\left(X_{n},f\left(X_{n}\right)\right)=\mathbb{E}h\left(X_{n}\right)\to\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)=\mathbb{E}g\left(X,f\left(X\right)\right)$$
This for every continuous and bounded $g$.

This justifies the statement
that $\left(X_{n},f\left(X_{n}\right)\right)$ convergences weakly
to $\left(X,f\left(X\right)\right)$ if $f$ is continuous.

---

**edit**:

This proof also works if the condition that $f$ is continuous is replaced by the condition that $X$ is a.s. not a discontinuity point of function $f$ (hence is a.s. not a discontinuity point of function $h$).

Comment: But can't we use the mapping theorem (for example theorem 1.18 on page 6 of http://www.math.chalmers.se/~serik/C-space.pdf) for measurable functions with a negligible set of continuities?

Comment: Well, there is at least an extra condition then. The probability that $X\in D_f$ must be $0$, wich is not the case in my answer. That is a weakening of the condition that $D_f=\varnothing$, i.e. that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes I meant negligible set of discontinuities rather than finite

Comment: If $h$ denotes the function mentioned in my answer then $x\in D_f\iff x\in D_h$ so that $P(X\in D_f)=P(X\in D_h)$. So the condition $P(X\in D_f)=0$ is the same as $P(X\in D_h)=0$. So my answer can be adapted on that.